# Did the Avengers talk about the arc reactor in Tony's chest in the first movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-avengers-2012

The Avengers aren't that concerned about the arc reactor in Tony's chest even though they should be, did Tony tell them?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Why should they be concerned? The whole world knows about Tony's arc reactor.

Comment: Yeah but they should be atleast a little concerned because what would happen if it shut down mid-battle they really wouldn't know what to do?

Comment: Also im asking if the fellow Avengers would really know what to do in this case scenario?

Comment: @Debbie If you want to keep the question open, try to explain what you find interesting or concerning.  In other words: 1. What is it that they aren't concerned about?  2. Why should they be concerned? 4. What about their behavior makes you suspect that Tony hasn't told them whatever it is he should have told them?  Mention those things, and make them part of the question, rather than just as a comment under the question.  And, lastly, make sure that they are all centered around a single question, not two.  If you have another thing you want to ask, make that a separate post.

Comment: Oh OK thank you I will try that next time!

Answer (score 2):

The only on screen conversation we have is between Bruce and Tony when they're having a little bit of a verbal contest.

> **Bruce Banner:** Ah, see. I don't get a suit of armor. I'm exposed, like a nerve. It's a nightmare.
>
> **Tony Stark:** You know, I've got a cluster of shrapnel, trying every second to crawl its way into my heart. (points at the MINI-ARC REACTOR in his chest) This stops it. This little circle of light. It's part of me now, not just armor. It's a... terrible privilege.
>
> **Bruce Banner:** But you can control it.
>
> <sub>*The Avengers*</sub>

That doesn't mean they don't talk about it off-screen. In fact they most probably do in a  similar manner to Tony with Bruce. However, the audience doesn't need to see that, we've already had the mini catch up scene with Bruce and a whole origin film on it.

I'm not sure why anyone would really need to be worried by it in his chest. It keeps him alive and powers his suit but seems to be very well protected having lasted a lot of fights. If anything Tony is *more* protected than the rest of them, having a fancy protective suit.